# segmentation fault (core dumped) error when trying to copy from an array

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors

trying to copy stuff from b into a but i get that error
someone told me it means i'm trying to access memory that i'm not allowed to, but i don't know what should i do to make it compile.

`replace(txt , code);`

```
string replace(string a , string b)
{
    string alpha[26] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz"};

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        for(int n = 0; n < 26; n++)
        {
            if(a[i] == alpha[n])
            {
                a[i] = b[n];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

i'm a beginner so no comments about clean coding or syntactic sugar or stuff like that just help me resolve this please

Comment: C does not have a type `string` so this code won't even compile.  Even if you add a `typedef char *string;`, you still have `word` which is never defined anywhere.

Comment: it compiles cause simply this is not the whole code there is stuff that i didn't post

Comment: That indicates the problems are mostly/partly in the parts you did not post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some problems with understending [pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer), so I recommend you to read about them. Also consider reading about [datatypes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) and [types from STL you are using](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string). (cause std::string is already an array of values so, when you are creating std::string[26], you actually are creating pointer to a pointer)

I guess you have are trying to do something like that:

```
std::string replace(string a , string b)
{
    std::string alpha = {"abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz"};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(size_t n = 0; n < alpha.size(); ++n)
        {
            if(a[i] == alpha[n])
            {
                a[i] = b[n];
                i++; // Also, I think you doesnt need this line, cause you already incrementing i in for loop
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Also you have used `strlen()` on your string, that also is not really correct, cause it is used on char values. If you whant to get length of a string it is better to use `string.lenght()`

Also, It is better to use `size_t` or `unsigned int` instead of `int` in this case, cause you don't need negative numbers in order to parce these strings. ()

Comment: this is actually a problem set from cs50 week 2 and i know nothing about pointers yet

Comment: @MEDesings: you can't understand strings in C without first understanding pointers.  If the class tries to teach them to you in the wrong order, it is seriously broken.